# Emails are stripped when printing from Outlook 2003

Tags: printing, microsoft-outlook-2003

Sometimes my emails are stripped (mostly in the right side). I have checked that the margins are properly set in Outlook and also the printer settings. Every thing seems to be OK.
Is there an workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by Internet Explorer (a friend of mine had the same problem and found the solution after 3 weeks)

Open IE to check the margins (File | Page Setup) and set them to the default .75 for all items. Now try to print the email.

Comment: It was hard to believe that IE was the problem... but you were right